# How to read in csv with FSharp.Data

Tags: f#, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I am trying to use the CsvProvider from FSharp.Data following the example here: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

In the example they define a type and then use the type but it looks like they are doing it in interactive mode. I am trying to do the same thing in my main but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

In the eample they do the following:

```
type Stocks = CsvProvider<"../data/MSFT.csv">
```

This is my attempt:

```
open System
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data

    // Process execution params
    // args(0) = nesting level
    // args(1) = csv file name
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args: string[]) =
    printfn "Arguments passes in: %A" args
    // F# searches the following directory at runtime : C:\Users\userName\source\repos\crawlerF\crawlerF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\test.csv'.
    // It is therefore necessary to provide the top level of the repo for the file read by prepending ../../../../ to the file name
    let filePath = "../../../../" + args.[1]  
    type urls = CsvProvider<filePath>
0
```

I get a few syntax errors when I try to define the urls variable. Why is this the case? I am new to F# so a more novice explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, it can be helpful to include details of any errors you're experiencing in the question. Not a big deal in this case because you've provided a code sample that allows others to reproduce the syntax errors, but worth bearing in mind in the future ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

1. You can't define types within a function, so you need to move the definition of `urls` out of the `main` function and into a module or namespace.
2. Type providers give you an easy way to generate types rather than defining them yourself manually, but these types still need to be generated at compile-time. This means that any parameter you pass to a type provider must be static, i.e. must have a value at compile-time.

   In your case, the `filePath` of your sample CSV file is the only parameter you're passing to the `CsvProvider`, but because this value is derived from a command line argument it is only known at runtime. To pass a static file name to the `CsvProvider` you can use a literal string, e.g.

   ```ml
   // Option 1: Use an inline literal string, like in the example from FSharp.Data.
   type Urls = CsvProvider<"test.csv">
   ```

   ```ml
   // Option 2: Use a named literal so that the compiler knows this value is static.
   let [<Literal>] FilePath = "test.csv"
   type Urls = CsvProvider<FilePath>
   ```
3. This may just be a formatting error in your code sample, but in order to return the `0` from your `main` function, it must be indented so that it's recognised as the last expression of that code block.

Putting this all together gives you something like the following:

```ml
open FSharp.Data

module Program =
    // The `Urls` type is now defined within a module.
    // This type is generated at compile-time from the sample file.
    // Assumes the sample file 'test.csv' exists in the project folder at compile-time.
    type Urls = CsvProvider<"test.csv">

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        // Use the generated `Urls` type to load some data at runtime.
        let urls = Urls.Load("...")
        // ...
        // Return an integer exit code.
        0
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I need to be able to handle a file name as input so it seems like this approach won't work for what I need but it does answer the question I posed.

Comment: The file that you pass to CsvProvider<> to create the type doesn't have to be the file you pass to the Load() method.  So create an example file as part of your project and use that to create the type, then when you get the real file name pass that to the Load() method on the type to read in the data.